# Deletion of table takes too long

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-delete

I am trying to delete a big table (11 GB size).

The table is so big because of a bug in the application who writes the table.
The table is a kind of custom made db change log in which by mistake updates to blob fields are logged too (causing the `DATALENGTH(OneSpecificField)` to be over 140MB in some cases for a single record, while the expected max size should have been 2 kB).

I tried to delete the table by running

```
DELETE CUSTOM_LOG
GO
```

The execution takes more than 10 minutes, being a production DB I do not like to wait forever (even if the users do not experience significant problems, since logging is now disabled).

If no one is accessing the table why it should take so long?

Comment: `DELETE` logs individual row deletions. Use `TRUNCATE TABLE CUSTOM_LOG`. This logs individual pages. Both can be rolled back.

Comment: interesting, i assume the log will not suffer in this way

Comment: That solution only works for tables that are not referenced by foreign keys. If you need to delete such tables, using DELETE remains an option, but then I would suggest you delete the table in batches of (for example) 10000 rows: `WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM CUSTOM_LOG) DELETE TOP (10000) FROM CUSTOM_LOG;` That performs faster than a single DELETE query and it will keep your transaction log from blowing up.

Comment: thanks for this extra soluion, my table was not referenced. i will add the `while exists` idea to my toolbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the table is not referenced by a FK, you can use `TRUNCATE TABLE CUSTOM_LOG`, it should work much faster

Comment: `TRUNCATE TABLE` worked like a breeze, being a log table no FK were referencing it